# Serializer all models with one serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, sqlalchemy

I'm new in django-rest and during my studies i came across the issue of a unique serialization. Normally, I would create one serializer for each model created, but i want to create just one serializer for all models. In a dynamic way.

**[EDIT]**

I'm using `Django REST Framework` integration with `SQLAlchemy`, so models came from sqlalchemy. I'm using `django-rest-witchcraf`t too, who offering supported for sqlalchemy orm.

Example:

*models.py*

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String())


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String())
    fullname = sa.Column(sa.String())
    password = sa.Column(sa.String())

    _group_id = sa.Column('group_id', sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey('groups.id'))
    group = sa.orm.relationship(Group, backref='users')


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email_address = sa.Column(sa.String(), nullable=False)

    _user_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = sa.orm.relationship(User, backref='addresses')
```

I try to do something like this:

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = None
        session = session
        fields = '__all__'
```

But I'm getting a NoneType as an answer:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Which makes sense, considering the skeleton of the serializer. I know this question was asked before, but I found no solution in the previous topic and nowhere else. I will probably have to work with the serializer ***init***, but I still have no idea how to do it.

I don't want a ready answer, of course, just an idea of ​​how to do this.

Comment: Probably you may need to write a lot of things on your own. [Here, in `serializers.py`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) , you can see a plenty of usage of ***`self.Meta`*** which is supposed to retrieve the model class. *"The idea"* is, go through the source code and implement things the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Django's ModelSerializer works for Django models but you're using SQLAlchemy which isn't part of Django. So this isn't going to work.

Django also doesn't provide a way to serialize multiple models as part of the same serializer.

What you can do is to Create a field for users in your `Group` serializer - that way you can have all users with their nested address in one place:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
    users = serializers.RelatedField(source='user', read_only=True)
```

Comment: I would like not to focus on the *SQLAlchemy* but this statement from the OP, *"....but i want to create just one serializer for all models. In a dynamic way..."*

Comment: @YPCrumble, I'm actually using Django REST Witchcraft which adds support for sqlalchemy. The import __from rest_witchcraft import__ serializers have a **ModelSerializer**, unfortunately i think he doesn't have the relatedfield method. I'm going to edit my post, I should have specified that I was using witchcraft. Thanks for help me :)

Comment: @Guilherme it looks like you could use `HyperlinkedIdentityField` from rest witchcraft.